# how to install skype in ubuntu 61.0.1 (64-bit)

Tags: uninstall, skype

I'm trying to install skype in Ubuntu software or terminal, but always showing unable to install Skype, snap "skype" has "install-snap" change in progress. or cannot perform the following tasks.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Ubuntu 16.04?

Create a new file: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list

Edit that new file and add this line:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
```

Then on the command line type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install skypeforlinux
```